# have a new .gitignore tell me if any file already matches tracked files

Tags: git, gitignore

is there a way to parse a .gitignore and tell me if i already have some files that match the ignores so that i know to remove them or change my .gitignore?

example is that i have git tracking my `imgs` directory, and i wish to ignore all of windows `Thumbs.db`, and also tell me if I have any left over in my repository being tracked so that i can remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `git ls-files --ignored`.  You might have to play with the options, but `ls-files` is the right starting point for writing a script that matches files using the excludes patterns.

Comment: reading the man page, `git ls-files --ignore --exclude-standard` seems to do exactly what i wanted. thanks!